# Как правильно отправить статью на сервер node

Tags: ajax, node.js, request

Есть фронт на Angular и бэк на express. На фронте юзер создает статью. В этой статье есть поля с различными типами данных. Статья будет отправляться на сервер условно в виде такого объекта:

```
{
  name: 'Название статьи',
  preText: 'Предисловие',
  text: 'Основной текст',
  isActive: true,
  count: 15,
  mainImg: ???,
  pretextImg: ???,
  otherImg: ???
}
```

Вопрос в том, что в этой статье есть изображения. Их может быть разное кол-во и в разных местах. Как правильно отправить такую статью на бек? Можно ли картинки отправить внутри этого объекта, или их слать отдельным запросом? Если только отдельным, то как потом понять, какое изображение откуда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сначала отсылать картинки на сохранение.

   1. Сервер сохраняет на диск картинку.
   2. Сервер в базу добавляет запись (id, путь до картинки).
   3. Сервер возвращает клиентц id картинки из базы.
2. Клиент после отправки всех картинок в данные по статье вписывает id этих картинок из базы (те, что сервак возвращал при отправке картинок клиентом).
3. Клиент отправляет на сервер запрос на сохранение статьи.

Comment: Большое спасибо за такое доступное объяснение. Осталось непонятно только одно - как идентифицировать фотографии на сервере. По названиям? Клиент отправляет 10 фоток из разных мест статьи. Сервер их сохраняет и возвращает клиенту айдишники. Но сервер должен вернуть не просто массив айдишников, а с какими-то ключами (mainImg, preview и т.д.)

Comment: При отправки картинок на сохранение можете какой-то доп. параметр передавать и его же возвращать потом.